# CSS left !important not overriding previous left value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with the following CSS:

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    left: 625px;
    display: none;
    color: #515151;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

This gets displayed via a jQuery click function which adds a class with the rule `display: block`. I use the following JavaScript to test whether or not the div is being displayed on a mobile device and, if so, it changes the `left` property:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  $('#div1').css({'left':'535px !important'});
  var left = $('#div1').css('left');
  alert(left);
}
```

The problem is, the rule doesn't get overridden! The `alert` returns the original value of the `left` property. Why is this not working?

**NOTE:** If it helps, this div is positioned in a div with `position: static`.

Comment: Both values are 535px so you didn't really change the value

Comment: Sorry. See edit.

Comment: `!important` isn't needed here anyway - local styles (`style="..."` attribute, which is also what JavaScript/jQuery set the style in) override any styles in stylesheets.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Except the ones declared as `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important` in `css` function is a known closed [issue](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173) which was not fixed. You can either remove the `!important` from the above or can try following alternate.

```js
console.log($("#abc").css('left'));
document.getElementById("abc").style.setProperty("left", "525px", "important");
console.log($("#abc").css('left'));
```

```css
#abc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    left: 535px;
    display: none;
    color: #515151;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">Test</div>
```

Please note, you can also **create a class** with the styles mentioned and can add the class as well.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use the id of the element as a reference only and move it's CSS styles to a new class with you will add to the div element.

Once the new left value is always the same you can have a separate class which you can add to the element when it fulfills the condition as follows.

```
<!-- div element -->
<div id="div1" class="element">...</div>

.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    left: 625px;
    display: none;
    color: #515151;
    z-index: 100;
}

.div-left {
    left: 535px !important;
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
if(<condition>) {
    $('#div1').addClass('div-left');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, changing the position of the parent div to `relative` worked. Wish I’d tried that in the first place!